# Pass Arguments between classes in Java " different packages "

Tags: java

I need to pass an argument between two classes in different packages.

For example, I have an `int a` in class `A` in package `AA`.. I need to pass it to class `B` in package `BB` which will change the value of a and pass it back to class `A`.

Comment: Is it a static field?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Some code with more specific questions would be helpful.

Comment: You can not change the value of an int. Primitives are (by nature) immutable.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster do you mean primitives or literals? Variables of primitive types are mutable like any other variable in Java (unless they are declared `final`)...

Comment: Classes don't pass arguments.  Methods do.  Or more precisely, method *calls* do.

Comment: @Turing85 I meant primitives (int, double, float etc). You cannot do with them what OP suggests: "pass it to class B in package BB which will change the value of a and pass it back to class A" because they are in effect immutable. If you change the value of a primitive you are creating a new primitive value, not changing an existing instance (because there is no instance, because it is a primitive). There is no spoon, so to speak (-:

Comment: @AdriaanKoster This is correct, but calling this "immutable" seems wrong to me since "immutable" is a property of instances of certain classes (e.g. `String` instances). The effect you describe is the nature of call-by-value.

Answer (score 0):

Either Use fully qualified class name or import it in another program . E.g if you want to create an object of `class A` which is in `AA` package in `class B` which is in different package, use

```
AA.A obj = new AA.A();
```

Now call the method which you want to pass value to,  using this obj reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

The above code did not work for me. I had to change the import in package B to make it work.

```
package BB;

import AA.A;

public class B {

public int change_a(int a){
    return a+1;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You should be passing arguments like this

```
package AA;
import BB.B;


public class A {
    int a = 5;

    private void play() {
        B b = new B();
        // Here we are passing the int argument to a method in different class and different package
        int new_a = b.change_a(a);
        System.out.println("a after the change is "+ new_a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new A().play();
    }
}
```

And your class B

```
package BB;
import BB.A;


public class B {


    public int change_a(int a){
        return a+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I guess,..." so why do you post a speculative answer instead of asking for clarification in the comments?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes, I should had asked him. Thanks for the suggestion.